# The JSON binary value contains invalid data

Tags: mysql, json

So when I run a query that aggregates results from a subquery into a JSON array containing JSON objects, i get the following error : `The JSON binary value contains invalid data`

This works on 8.0.15 but not on 8.0.17 and onwards. The bug seems to be related to the length of the string in the subquery's field. 1000 character seems to be the breaing point. So if you remove characters from jsonString for it to be under 1000 characters it works.

Here is a sample query :

```
SELECT 1 
    , CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT JSON_OBJECT('sJsonData', rInt.jsonString) ORDER BY rInt.val DESC),']')
FROM (
(SELECT 1 AS val , '{"html":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mattis diam ac purus dictum, sed consequat quam dignissim. Mauris sagittis urna ut turpis accumsan sodales. Praesent porttitor felis sagittis metus tristique vulputate. In nec nisl ipsum. Pellentesque sem ipsum, dignissim sit amet dictum ac, iaculis id elit. Fusce eu pellentesque leo. In suscipit felis at ultricies tristique.Suspendisse aliquet ligula quis risus ultricies aliquet. Etiam laoreet augue leo, id malesuada nisi mattis eget. Donec sit amet ultricies orci. Aenean vitae urna vel ligula mollis fringilla. Suspendisse quis auctor nisi, vel scelerisque ligula. Fusce ornare, enim a placerat tempus, sapien erat laoreet purus, ut ornare nulla risus nec dolor. Morbi dictum, odio non lacinia auctor, purus ex vulputate magna, nec dictum tortor turpis non quam. Ut commodo ut erat et sollicitudin. Aenean in scelerisque metus, et laoreet purus. Morbi nec viverra arcu. Nullam sed tempor elit, et molestie sem00000000000000"}' AS jsonString)
) AS rInt
```

I have tryed to cast the string as `utf8mb4` and changing it's collation but that doesn't fix the issue.

I will also be filing a bug on MySQL as this doesn't seem to make sense. It also looks like the issue is linked to [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95698)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) has a limit of 1024. You need to set group_concat_max_len to higher value, like this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 60000;
```

Db fiddle found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/44rahPRgwfyBSunZ7vAMSE/0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did not think of checking that as the error doesn't point in the direction of the group_concat