# "The JSON binary value contains invalid data" error prevents further debugging - MySql

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

Im using `Amazon Aurora MySql 2.7.2` with `Jet brains DataGrip`.

Some data in one of the tables is incorrect.
The data consists of 2 columns:
`Id` (type = varchar(350)) and `Dependencies` (type = json).

When Im trying to get all the data (`Select * FROM MyTable`) or when selecting a specific data thats known to be incorrect (`Select * FROM MyTable Where Id = 'someIdOfincorrectJson'`) Im getting an error:

> [HY000][3142] The JSON binary value contains invalid data.

So some data in the `Dependencies` column is incorrect.

When I select an Id of a valid json it returns well (as expected).

I found this: [The JSON binary value contains invalid data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429168/the-json-binary-value-contains-invalid-data) but increasing both `max_allowed_packet` and `group_concat_max_len` variables didnt help.

I am not sure of how to proceed debugging this issue as there is no data to inspect :)

Any ideas?